# Newsletter com tradução incompleta

Tags: bug, internacionalização, newsletter

Olhando a newsletter do SoPT vi que muitas coisas não são traduzidos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não sei de quem é a responsabilidade sobre a newsletter, mas achei válido trazer isso ao meta.